# How do I make a gerrit repository secret

Tags: gerrit

New to gerrit and administration part of access control. We have a couple of gerrit repos and groups. One repo is secret and is visible only to members of a certain group. Cannot wrap my head around exactly what settings or access settings that makes this possible.

It is not the project options state setting “hidden” that I’m looking for. Since the secret repo state is “active” but not showing up on the list and not accessible by other groups. Do I configure the repo I want to make secret in the project.config file or in the access inheritance that is inherited from “All-Projects”? What do I need to configure then? Like: refs/* READ “Allow = Secret Group”? Would this make the repo secret, not showing up in the repo list and only accessible by “Secret Group”? Tried READ DENY to other groups but still showing up. v.2.16.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right:

refs/* READ ALLOW => grant project list permission

refs/* READ DENY => deny project list permission

But...

A project is considered visible if **any** ref is visible for that user, so check if there's an explicit READ ALLOW on refs/meta/dashboard or any other ref.

See [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1TUwrCBljGqI4jLUA0TthuMLRwtqcUI7T9XH5kakrbpg) more details about this.

Comment: Yup it’s the dashboard that needs to be explicitly set to BLOCK.